# jQuery Mobile hijax redirects -- how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, hijax

I would like to run a full page refresh when I'm at my site's login page, as the login page has an entirely different layout than when I'm logged in.
One problem occurs when a user that was previously logged in, navigates around on my site, and is automatically logged out and redirected to the login page as the result of a timeout.
jQuery Mobile "hijax" this page and now the layout is ruined.

How can I prevent jQuery Mobile from "hijaxing" a redirect?

None of what is mentioned here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html is relevant, because all the links are valid and does not require any of the special attributes, until of course a timeout occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understanded the problem correctly. I thought about 2 possible alternatives:

-you can use ajax to verify if the user is logged in, before opening the link. (using a listener and  changePage). If the ajax returns that you are not logged in, reload the page instead of loading the link.

-use the pagebeforeshow listener to identify if the loaded page is the login page (for example, checking the presence of a specific DOM element that is only present in the login page). If so, reload the page.

Comment: Thanks! First alternative is a solution. However, using pagebeforeshow does not work very well. It does work, but the stuff is actually inserted into the DOM before reload completes :/ It's unfortunate that all pages require two requests per link.

Comment: For the second one, you can try to hide the DOM until you haven't checked if you are logged. Example: $("body").hide(); if ($("#some_element_that_is_in_login_page").length !== 0) window.locationblabla; else $("body").show();